# Building libsoxr to Webassembly leads to function signature mismatch error

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to build libsoxr to WebAssembly with emscripten. Everything I try leads to a `RuntimeError: function signature mismatch` error when calling the `soxr_create` function.  I'm using the `latest` tag of emscripten. I also tried the provided examples and the behavior is the same. I tried using NodeJS and Chromium.

Here's how to reproduce:

```
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/soxr/code
cd soxr
emcmake cmake -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .
emmake make
node examples/2-stream.js
```

The stack trace is:

```
exception thrown: RuntimeError: function signature mismatch,RuntimeError: function signature mismatch
    at wasm-function[50]:0xf72e
    at wasm-function[49]:0xe90d
    at wasm-function[60]:0x1057f
    at wasm-function[14]:0xcac
    at wasm-function[13]:0xb53
    at wasm-function[11]:0x699
...
```

When building a file with only a `main` function calling `soxr_create` and building with `-g --profiling`, here's the stack trace I'm getting:

```
exception thrown: RuntimeError: function signature mismatch,RuntimeError: function signature mismatch
    at dft_stage_init (wasm-function[68]:0x1b8e2)
    at _soxr_init (wasm-function[66]:0x190be)
    at rate_create (wasm-function[88]:0x1f8fa)
    at initialise (wasm-function[124]:0x43c90)
    at soxr_set_io_ratio (wasm-function[122]:0x4373f)
    at soxr_create (wasm-function[119]:0x43213)
    at __original_main (wasm-function[135]:0x45646)
    at main (wasm-function[136]:0x45684)
    at /home/geekuillaume/code/wasm-audio-resampler/soxr_wasm.js:1635:22
    at callMain (/home/geekuillaume/code/wasm-audio-resampler/soxr_wasm.js:2377:15)
```

I've tried using emscripten sanitizer but it does nothing.

Comment: This normally happens when function pointers in C are used with the wrong signature.

If you use `wasm-objdump -d` on the wasm binaryen you should see a call_indirect instruction at the offset given within the `dft_stage_init` function (0x1b8e2).   This should allow you figure out which source line corresponds do.  

I don't see any obvious indirect calls that stand out in that source code but you should be able to figure it out.    Hopefully this is something that is fixable in the source rather than a compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You are right, it's from a call_indirect instruction. I found that it was generated from the `rdft_forward_setup` call in file `cr.c`. This function is from a function table `RDFT_CB` which has multiple functions signatures. Could this be because of this? I don't know what to do to try and debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. The Soxr lib was wrongfully casting a function pointer. The pointed function was expecting no arguments but was casted to a function receiving one int as argument. I wrote a patch to fix this and everything is working fine! There is more information about this in the [Emscripten documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/guidelines/function_pointer_issues.html).